# Where to set session in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm reading the Codeigniter 2.2 tutorial and I am not clear on how to use sessions for logging in.

Say I have a login.php, which checks user data with the database. Then if its ok then I should set the session in a controller?

```
  $this->load->library('session');
```

And then in say admin.php page I should check if session exists by? :

```
 $this->session->user_data('item'); ??
```

Or how do I check if the person is logged in?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session), to do anything custom within session you need to load the session library.  If you plan to use session throughout your application, I would recommend [autoloading](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) the library.  You do this from within config/autoload.php.

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Then you won't have to use `$this->load->library('session');` on every page.

After the library is loaded, set your custom information, maybe based off some information from your database. So in your case, this would be in login.php:

`$this->session->set_userdata('userId', 'myId');` where `userId` would be the name of the session variable, and `myId` would be the value.

Then, on subsequent pages (admin.php), you could check that the value is there.

`if($this->session->userdata('userId') == '') { //take them back to signin }`

Comment: I'd probably make a base controller MY_Controller.php in the core directory (maybe a base controller for the admin section and a base controller for the normal site)  That controller could check whether or not you are logged in.  That way you don't need to have your logic on every admin controller.  Also I think it's fine to include the session setting logic in either the model or controller.  It's up to you.  A lot of people like Skinny Controllers and Fat Models or vice versa.

Comment: @Overachiever is exactly right.  Creating your own MY_Controller to extend the CI controller is a great way to simplify the code and make it easy to validate all other pages from one spot.

Comment: No, no, Im not trying to do anything custom with the session, I was just trying to find out a standard way of using a session to check if a person is logged in.

Comment: CI will set a few values automatically when the session library is loaded: session_id, ip_address, user_agent, and last_activity.  The standard way would usually involve adding a custom piece of information, then validating that piece along with possibly the `last_activity` that CI adds.

Comment: So I generate a random string to use as a 'custom piece of information' and then store it in a db? If you have say hundreds of users loggin in and logging out then it's a burden on a db. Or this is how it is done in practice?

Comment: I should prob do more research, I was hoping to save time on this. Thanks anyway

Comment: There are a few different ways you could do it, but, as an example, in one of my apps, each user has a userId.  When the user signs in, I put that userId into my session.  Then, on each page I verify that the userId has a value.  That is a simple approach, but the difference is rather than just having a CI session, you have a session and a piece that only has a value IF the user successfully signed in, where a general CI session can exist even if the user never validated themself.

Answer (score 4):

1. load session library

   ```
   $this->load->library('session');
   ```
2. set session

   ```
   $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
   ```
3. unset session

   ```
   $this->session->unset_userdata($_SESSION['email']); // $this->session->sess_destroy();
   ```

Comment: set session in CodeIgniter StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

To set user session

```
$the_session = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$this -> session -> set_userdata($the_session);
```

To read user session

```
$foo = $this -> session -> userdata('key1');
```

You need `$this->load->library('session');`  every time prior you use CI session functions. Or you can set it up in autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Comment: So I have to set session array values myself? It doesnt do it automatically?

Comment: @VeganSv Yes, you define it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('session'); // load the session library
$this->session->userdata("email") // check for the variable "email" in session array
```

Comment: provide relevant description/notes to support your answer. @siddharth shukla

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.